# Bottle.py - split string array (CSV)

Tags: bottle

I have a small web demo pulling data from into a CSV file, which I want to display on a web page. I plan to use Bottle.py, but I cannot split the string into an array. There will be multiple lines in the CSV file, which I will read in split and then create a table.

```
from bottle import run, debug, template, get, redirect, request, response, static_file, route, os, sys
LOG_FILENAME = "data.csv"
@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    readfiledata()
    print(reader)
    array = reader.split(',')

return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=reader)
```

Comment: First of all you don't declared reader variable. Secondly you don't pass any CSV data to template.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (using `csv` module from the Standard Library):

```
import csv
from bottle import route, jinja2_template

@route('/csv')
def show_csv():
    with open('data.csv') as fo:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(fo)
        table = [row for row in csv_reader]
    return jinja2_template('templ.html', table=table)
```

`templ.html` (I'm using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templates which I prefer over Bottle's built-in templating language):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    {# Table header #}
    <th>Foo</th>
    <th>Bar</th>
    <th>Baz</th>
  </tr>
{% for row in table %}
  <tr>
{% for cell in row %}
    <td>{{ cell }}</td>
{% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```